# Get sunset and sunrise times from GNOME night-mode

Tags: shell-script, timezone

GNOME has a night-mode feature that automatically makes the screen a bit more reddish after the sunset, till the sunrise.

Both sunset and sunrise times can be fetched automatically from - I assume - the latitude and longitude of the user.

I want to get those two times in a bash script. How to do that?

Comment: Related over at StackOverflow: [I need a sunrise/sunset webservice api](//stackoverflow.com/q/4564972)

Comment: I don't want to get the times from a webservice. I want to get them from the system that already have them.